# Profile object does not deserialize `core_attributes` correctly - Azure Devops Python API

Tags: python, api, azure-devops

This is a copy of an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/365) I opened on the project itself, so sorry in advance for the duplicate.

I am trying to get some profiles by id and I cannot figure out if there is a bug in this library or if I am not using it correctly, but when I get a profile with a call like:

```
profile_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_profile_client()
a_profile = profile_client.get_profile(authenticated_user_id, details=True)
```

I see that data like the `Avatar` is coming back from the http request log

```
...
'Avatar': {'descriptor': {'attributeName': 'Avatar',
    'containerName': 'Core'},
   'value': {'value': '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',
    'timeStamp': '2020-12-09T16:53:10.5466667+00:00',
    'size': 'medium',
    'isAutoGenerated': True},
   'timeStamp': '2020-12-09T16:53:10.5466667+00:00'},
...
```

but if I serialize the Profile object, I do not see anything

```
a_profile.as_dict()

...
{'core_attributes': {'DisplayName': {},
  'PublicAlias': {},
  'EmailAddress': {},
  'UnconfirmedEmailAddress': {},
  'CountryName': {},
  'TermsOfServiceVersion': {},
  'TermsOfServiceAcceptDate': {},
  'Avatar': {},
  'ContactWithOffers': {}},
...
```

and even if I get the Avatar object from `a_profile.core_attributes`, the object does not seem to contain anything.

NOTE: using the v5.1 gives the exact same result

Is there a problem with the library or I am not using it correctly?

Thanks a lot in advance e for your help.

**UPDATE**:
I made some additional research and realized that this change actually triggers a serialization

```
diff --git a/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/profile/models.py b/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/profile/models.py
index b527f6c..27f9e0d 100644
--- a/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/profile/models.py
+++ b/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/profile/models.py
@@ -264,11 +264,8 @@ class CoreProfileAttribute(ProfileAttributeBase):

     """

-    _attribute_map = {
-    }
-
-    def __init__(self):
-        super(CoreProfileAttribute, self).__init__()
+    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
+        super(CoreProfileAttribute, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I am still not convinced this is a correct desirialization, but I am pretty sure that now there is a bug in the library.

Comment: How about using V5_1? It seems 6.0 still in preview: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/tree/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT thanks for your comment, but v5.1 gives the exact same result: I looked up the code and that class has not actually changed much

Comment: Check this issue to see whether it helps you: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/188.

Comment: I do not think it helps: that issue was actually helpful to get the Azure devops user id of the authenticated user in the client.
The object that is returned there does not contain all the infos that the profile endpoint returns.

Comment: Which authentication type do you use? Are you able to get successful response when you run api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0? How about using Users - Get api `graph_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_graph_client()
a_graph = graph_client.get_user(user_descriptor)
`?

Comment: I use the `BasicTokenAuthentication` with OAuth tokens. Yes, I get successful responses: if I enable the logging, I can see the data coming from the HTTP request. Also if you look at the `UPDATE` above, you can see that changing a bit the library, I get somewhere. I think it is a problem with the python client library and not with the APIs.
Using a different api/client is an option, but I guess not in the scope of this question.
I already more or less addressed my problem by using the raw underlining request and JSON response, but I would like to use the actual profile object.